# Long press gesture recognizer on UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, long-press

I'm working on the Minesweeper game, I want to add the flag when user long tap on a tile of the gameboard.
I've implemented this code:

For every button in gameboard:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressTap:)];
            longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
            [self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

In self, the method *longPressTap:*

```
- (void)longPressTap:(Tile *)sender {
        if (sender.block.marking ==  MARKING_FLAGGED) {
            // if already a flag I mark as a blank tile, with color defined for gameboard
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5);
            sender.block.marking = MARKING_BLANK;
            self.flagCount++;
        }
        else{
            // if it's not a flag I mark as a flag and set the flag image for the tile
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NAME_FLAG] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            sender.block.marking = MARKING_FLAGGED;
            self.flagCount--;
        }
}
```

And of course self is my *UIGestureRecognizerDelegate*.
But when I try to long press on a tile, the app crash and give this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILongPressGestureRecognizer block]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cf2b00'
```

What should I do? I'm at the very beginning with Obj-C programming so if someone can help me and explain what I did wrong I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)showOptions:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender{

UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender.view;
NSLog(@"view tag %d",sender.view.tag);

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{

}
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
   [self.bubbleDelegate showOptionsForMessage:btn];
}
```

}

Comment: Great solution! This solves the issue of UILongPressGestureRecognizer firing again on touch up inside.

Answer (score 0):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILongPressGestureRecognizer block]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cf2b00'

From this error it is very clear app is crashing because of `[UILongPressGestureRecognizer block]`. `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` doesnt have a method called `block` so it is crashing.

```
- (void)longPressTap:(Tile *)sender {
}
```

As you expected in the implementation `sender` in this method is not `Tile` object, it is actually `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

The expected method is

```
- (void)longPressTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I thought was wrong, but passing UILongPressGestureRecognizer as parameter for longPressTap: 
how can I check what Tile user choose and mark it as a flag/blank? Sorry for noob questions but I'm trying to understand

Comment: use `[sender locationInView]` to find the location of touch from there you should have a logic to get the associated `Tile`

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem . Can I now what is "Tile" in argument.

```
- (void)longPressTap:(Tile *)sender
```

use this may be helpfull

```
- (void)longPressTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
```

and don't use direct Tile. Use Tile object direct here and make global object of this ..

Comment: I was passing Tile as a parameter because I didn't know how to identify the Tile selected by the user. So now I have:
- (void)longPressTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender 
But can you please give me a snippet for marking the tile as flag/blank? ty

Comment: try adding long tap gesture to Tile object instead of button, and use Tile object as sender argument, may it will work