# Detecting Touch and hold on screen IPhone (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

Im trying to find out how to detect a touch&hold on screen method in the game im making. Im using touches began for single taps (Making the character move up) When they touch and keep holding i want the character to move straight forward.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 //code to make him move up

    }
```

Any ideas on how to detect a touch&hold ?

Comment: I think you need to use UILongPressGestureRecognizer for touch and hold on screen

Comment: Do you know how i should write that ?

Comment: The code i mean

Comment: Please check my answer below, for more detailes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548263/swift-button-tap-and-long-press-gesture

Answer (score 2):

**Objective-c**

```
// Add guesture recognizer
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDidLongPress:)];
    [self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

// Call back event
- (void)buttonDidLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            // Code
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            //Code
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
// Add guesture recognizer
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
        self.button.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

// Call back event
func longPress(guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        switch guesture.state {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
            //Code
            break

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
            //Code
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Don't forgot to extend you class with UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

-(void) handleLongPress: (UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress {
switch (longPress.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        // Called when long press for minimum time duration
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        // Long pressed and dragged 
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized:
        // Successfully recognised Long touch
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
if (longPress.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    NSLog(@"LONG PRESSED");
}
```

}

Comment: I tried with no luck, where should i place :      UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

Comment: i put it in touchesbegan but it didnt work..

Comment: UILongPressGestureRecognizer will be alternative to touchesbegan, u should use one or the other

Comment: Do your things in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnd`. Code updated