# Long Press Recognize Gesture via Button - Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to make timer(in the label) that starts with a long press on the button. At the same time I want to change the long press button image when press the long press button. I leave button, I want the button revert back.

What might be wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var myBtn: UIButton!

func initGesture()
{

    {   let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTap(_:)))
        myBtn.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
    }
}

func TimerAction()
{
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(longTap), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    myBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "xxx.png"), for: .normal)


}
@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

func start()
{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController2.updateTime as (ViewController2) -> () -> ())), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func updateTimer () {
    count += 1
    let hours = Int(count) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(count) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(count) % 60
    label.text = String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds)
}

func reset()
{
    timer.invalidate()
    count = 0
    label.text = "00:00:00"

}
```

Comment: what's your code doing exaclt?

Comment: I'm trying to do something I write up. I knocked the myBtn on long press gesture recognize. Where am i wrong? @MohammadBashirSidani

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548263/swift-button-tap-and-long-press-gesture

Comment: Post your longTap method

Comment: You are calling updateTime method(not exist in your code) instead updateTimer  method in start method. Then set your images as  @Kiester solution.

Comment: @MarryJoe check out the answer and let me know if you have any confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can get TouchUpInside and TouchUpOutside also TouchDown action of button don't use the gesture.**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myBtn: UIButton!
var timer: NSTimer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      myBtn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonDown:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
      myBtn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonUp:", forControlEvents: [.TouchUpInside, .TouchUpOutside])
    }
func buttonDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    singleFire()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "rapidFire", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func buttonUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    count = 0
    label.text = "00:00:00"
}

func singleFire() {
    myBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "xxx.png"), for: .normal)
}

func rapidFire() {
    count += 1
    let hours = Int(count) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(count) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(count) % 60
    label.text = String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds)
}

}
```

Comment: nice one. but it increases the code for recognising a long press.

Comment: @jegadeesh thanks for the suggestion but I am showing the uses of action.

Comment: happy to help 

Answer (score 1):

You should implement button events instead of using the gesture recognisers here. The button events i talk about are TouchDown and TouchUpInside. TouchDown will tell you when a button is being pressed and touchupinside will tell you when the user lifted their finger from button.

So you will change the button image and start your timer on touchdown event. Then you will revert back on touchupinside event.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

set first the image of the button depending on its state.

```
    self.arrowIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "normalImage.png"), for: .normal)
    self.arrowIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "pressedImage.png"), for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: glad to help @MarryJoe!