# Button click is not working with UITapGestureRecognizer when i tapped first time on the button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have implement UITapGestureRecognizer and UILongPressGestureRecognizer  on button click.  My problem is when i tapped first time on button its not working but second time when i press the button its start working.

```
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTap(_:)))
    longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    button.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(normalTap(_:)))
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) 
 @objc func longTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("long tap")

}
@objc func normalTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){

    print("Normal tap")
}
```

Comment: Have you got this long press in a IBAction ButtonClicked?

Comment: Did you try to add only 1 tapGesture and check if the callback is triggered ?

Comment: why you are not tried `addTarget` alternate of `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: else use like `button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    button.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)` instead of `button.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture), button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)`

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548263/swift-button-tap-and-long-press-gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTap(_:)))
     longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
     button.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
 }


 @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
     let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(normalTap(_:)))
     tapGesture.delegate = self
     tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
     tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
     button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
 }

 @objc func longTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
     print("long tap")
 }

 @objc func normalTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
     print("Normal tap")
   }
}
```

Comment: make sense bro. I have placed both the  gestures in view did load then only works fine .Thanks for the clue .. Place these two gesture in view did load function so that i can voteup your answer.