# How to check tap on the button? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to check when User taps the button to do next actions. How it can be implemented? For example, I have this button:

```
@IBAction func ButtonSender(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

and I need to know when it is tapped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button tap and long press gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548263/button-tap-and-long-press-gesture)

Comment: when user will tap the button(yourButton) and is connected to method @IBAction func ButtonSender(_ sender: UIButton) you can print something here

Comment: Could you explain what's the problem?! your code snippet should be executed when user taps the button... what else?

Comment: your code is right, you will get the above event when button will tap

Comment: @AhmadF how can I check event when button is released?

Comment: @bibscy it should be the `touchUpInside`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is very simple

```
@IBAction func ButtonSender(_ sender: UIButton) {
      yourFunction()
      print("The button was tapped")
}
```

Comment: Wondering how could you understand the purpose of the question :D

Comment: @AhmadF awesome developer :)

Answer (score -1):

Build a variable of type Boolean initialize it with false then after hitting button change its value to true..

```
    @IBAction func ButtonSender(_ sender: UIButton) {
    isButtonTapped = true
    }
```